# Could you teach me a word to describe to mix two electrical signals?

Tags: word-choice

Would you kindly give me advice? I would like to express mixing two electrical signals of different freqencies and transmitting in one pair of metal wires. To overlap signals or to overlay signals are possible options I googled, but I can't have confidence.

Comment: Do you want to really "mix" them, or rather somehow manage to separate them on the other end?  To truly "mix" them, you would "sum" them or "add" them or (ta dah!) "mix" them.  To keep them separable you'd use some sort of "multiplexing" scheme.  (This is really a question for one of the electrical SEs, such as [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).)

Answer (score 3):

**Multiplexer** - demultiplexer?:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer
If the frequency domains of the two signals don't cross, you can simply use high pass/low pass filters to separate them at the end of your wires.